# Wrong time from clock

Tags: c, time

I have a program that counts the time to send or receive a amount of data. When I receive the data the clocks says it only takes about half of the time it actually takes.

Output from the terminal that recives the data:

```
Amount of data recived: 60296112/300000000
Time: 4
Start time: 3269
End time: 4849790
Clocks per sec: 1000000
```

And the output from the terminal that sends the data:

```
Sent 300000000 bytes of data
Time to send was 10.793425
```

The terminal that sends the data will send a stop signal after it has sent all other data. When I watch the terminal that receives the data I can see that it starts counting when the other terminal starts sending data and I can see it print out output from `clock()` way longer that the output says it does.

My code for the receive part:

```
static void recive_sock(int socket_fd,char *buffert, size_t buffert_size, struct sockaddr *other, socklen_t *other_size){
    clock_t start_t, end_t;
    long int total_time = 0;
    printf("Listning for data\n" );
    fflush(stdout);
    int run = 1;
    char start = 1;
    int amount = 0;
    int recive_length;

    while(run){
        recive_length = recvfrom(socket_fd, buffert, buffert_size, 0, other, other_size );
        if(recive_length < 0){
            die("Recvfrom failed");
        }
        if(strncmp(buffert, "HELLO!", 6) == 0){
            amount += recive_length;
            if(start == 1){
                start = 0;
                start_t = clock();
                printf("Start: %ld\n",start_t );
            }
            printf("%ld\n",clock() );
        }
        else if (strncmp(buffert, "die", 3) == 0) {
            run = 0;
            end_t = clock();
            printf("End %ld\n",end_t );
            total_time = (end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("Amount of data recived: %d/%d\nTime: %ld\nStart time: %ld\nEnd time: %ld\n,Clocks per sec: %ld", amount, AMOUNT, total_time, start_t, end_t, CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `clock()` returns processor time used, not time elapsed. More here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html#tag_16_62

Comment: Are you sure that data is actually sent out immediately after you start sending it? There might be internal buffering that delays sending until there is enough data to send. I think that code that sends the data is extremely relevant here.

Comment: 1) `if(recive_length < 0){` Check for EAGAIN here 2) `if (strncmp(buffert, "die", 3) == 0) {` TCP is stream based, it does not preserve "message boundaries", your "die" keyword could be anywhere in the buffert, maybe even across segments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `clock` will return the CPU time which is probably not what you are looking for, instead you want to use something like `gettimeofday` or `clock_gettime` for system that support it. Then you can compare the time before and after to get the time elapsed. For future readers, here is how to do it with `clock_gettime` if your system supports it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>                // for clock_gettime()

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int sum = 1;
    struct timespec t1, t2;
    double elapsedTime;

    // start timer
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t1);

    // do something here
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
            sum *= i+j;
        }
    }

    // stop timer
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t2);

    // compute and print the elapsed time in millisec
    elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;
    elapsedTime += (t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec) / 1000000.0;
    printf("%.3f ms elapsed\n", elapsedTime);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a simple example on how to measure time with `gettimeofday` (less accurate for high-precision timing):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>                // for gettimeofday()

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int sum = 1;
    struct timeval t1, t2;
    double elapsedTime;

    // start timer
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

    // do something here
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
            sum *= i+j;
        }
    }

    // stop timer
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

    // compute and print the elapsed time in millisec
    elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;
    elapsedTime += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;
    printf("%.3f ms elapsed\n", elapsedTime);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;` mind the sign. Use the absolute difference.

Comment: You NEVER want to use gettimeofday to measure elapsed time. It is the wrong function for that purpose. Use the appropriate Posix function -  clock_gettime

Comment: @Xofo I know of high-resolution timers and they are better suited for measuring time elapsed. However, it is not as wide supported as `gettimeofday` which is a good alternative if you want to trade off accuracy for platform support. I added an example demonstrating how to use `clock_gettime`.

Comment: >

gettimeofday if I remember correctly is not available on some embedded systems (like VxWorks) and is not a Posix function and is actually deprecated by the Open Group (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) ... I also had bad experiences with a hacked up version of it on an embedded board.

<

Comment: @Xofo oh, interesting. Thanks for letting me know.